# CompiledFunctionCall vs. LibraryFunction

Tags: compile

When compiling code to C, and the compiled code calls other compiled functions, I see `CompiledFunctionCall` in the output of `CompilePrint` most of the time. But sometimes, it's replaced by `LibraryFunction[<>,...]`. Could anybody explain the difference between these two?

EDIT: As an example, I would expect a `LibraryFunction` call in the following case. If I define:

```
compBinomial=Compile[{{n,_Real},{k,_Real}},
Which[
k==0.||k==n,
1,
n==0.,
0,
k<=Quotient[n,2],
Product[(n+1-i)/i,{i,1,k}],
True,
Product[(n+1-i)/i,{i,1,n-k}]
]
,CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed"
];
```

If I then define the following:

```
compsum=Compile[
{{n,_Integer},{m,_Integer},{j,_Integer}},
Round@Sum[
(-1)^k*compBinomial[n+m,n-k]*compBinomial[k+j,k]
,{k,0,n}]
,CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed",
CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True,
"InlineCompiledFunctions"->False}
];
```

I see `CompiledFunctionCall` in the output of `CompilePrint[compsum]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that `LibraryFunction` occurs if the function being called inside the other compiled function is a function that has been compiled to C, provided this function has been called with the right type of arguments. It seems that in other cases there is a `CompiledFunctionCall`.

As pointed out by Simon Woods in the comments below, there is a type mismatch in the example that you added later, so that in this case `CompiledFunctionCall` is used.

Be warned that this is based on very few examples, so this may not be the correct explanation.

Here is a simple example where compiled functions are called with the right type of arguments. First we compile it to the WVM and then to C and observe the difference.

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
cf = Compile[{{x}}, Sin[x]];
cf5 = Compile[{{x}}, cf[x^2], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False}];
cf5 // CompilePrint
```

> ```
> ...
> R2 = CompiledFunctionCall[ Hold[CompiledFunction[{x}, Sin[x], \
> -CompiledCode-]][ R1]]
> ...
> ```

```
cf2 = Compile[{{x}}, Sin[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
cf6 =
  Compile[{{x}}, cf2[x^2],
   CompilationOptions ->
    {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False}
   ];
cf6 // CompilePrint
```

> ```
> ...
> R2 = LibraryFunction[<>, compiledFunction12, {{Real, 0, Constant}}, \
> Real][ R1]]
> ...
> ```

**About LibraryFunction**

In a compiled function that has been compiled to C, a `LibraryFunction` will do all the work. A library function is a function that is part of a dynamically linked library that is loaded into the kernel. The dynamically linked library is the result of compiling C code.

The following code creates an expression with head `LibraryFunction`. It does this by loading a pre-compiled function from a library.

```
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo", "demo_I_I", {Integer}, Integer];
fun//Head
```

> ```
> LibraryFunction
> ```

You can also see a `LibraryFunction` in the definition of `cf2`

```
cf2//InputForm
```

> ```
> CompiledFunction[{10, 10.1, 
>   5468}, {_Real}, {{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 1}}, {}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, 
>   {{40, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {1}}, Function[{x}, Sin[x]], Evaluate, 
>   LibraryFunction["path/compiledFunction12.dylib", 
>   "compiledFunction12", 
>     {{Real, 0, "Constant"}}, Real]]
> ```

In the definition of `cf`, no such `LibraryFunction` is present.

**Skipping interaction with the CompiledFunction**

The compilation process in *Mathematica* is smart enough to figure out that a compiled function is compiled to C, so it knows that it can simply call the `LibraryFunction`, rather than interacting with some `CompiledFunction` object. In fact we can do the same manually. Let

```
libFunc = cf2[[9]]
```

> ```
> LibraryFunction[Function name: compiledFunction12 Argument count: 1]
> ```

So that we have defined `libFunc` as the `LibraryFunction` that does all the work for `cf2`.

Then we can do

```
libFunc[Pi]
```

> ```
>  1.22465*10^-16
> ```

**Conclusion**

My guess is that this explains the difference. When calling a function that has been compiled to the WVM, a `CompiledFunction` is really called. When using a  function that has been compiled to C, in the absence of a type mismatch,a shortcut is taken and the `LibraryFunction` is called directly.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer! I must have forgotten to compile the inner function to C in some cases, that's why I sometimes got `CompiledFunctionCall`.

Comment: Please see my updated question, I think I have found an exception to your answer.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer good example! I can only guess why it it uses a `CompiledFunctionCall` here. Perhaps the compiler doesn't care about the additional overhead, because the body of the compiled function is relatively large compared to this overhead. Or the compiler somehow cannot figure out it can use the shortcut. I suppose I should edit my answer slightly, thank you.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, in your question you are defining `compBinomial` to take real arguments but when you call it from within `compsum` you pass integer arguments. I think this type inconsistency is why the library function is not used.

Comment: That seems to have solved it, thanks! @JacobAkkerboom, could you add this info to your answer?